# Grid invoice add some attributes

Tags: magento-1.8, grid, invoice, backend

I actually wanna add sub total, total excluding tax and subtotal including tax in my invoice grid in the admin backend of magento. 
I know I have to change `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Invoice/Grid.php`, and I'm watching this file, but no idea of how to change it to make my wish.

-> I'm on Magento 1.8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

copy

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Invoice/Grid.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Invoice/Grid.php
```

you need to add below code at after  `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());`  in function _prepareCollection()

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
 $InvoicetableName = $resource->getTableName('sales/invoice');
  $collection->getSelect()
 ->joinLeft(
array('inovoicemain' =>$InvoicetableName ),
'inovoicemain.entity_id = main_table.entity_id',
array(
    'subtotal_incl_tax' => 'inovoicemain.subtotal_incl_tax',
    'subtotal' => 'inovoicemain.subtotal',

));
```

and 
 add below at _prepareColumns

```
$this->addColumn('subtotal_incl_tax', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('subtotal_incl_tax'),
    'index'     => 'subtotal_incl_tax',
    'type'      => 'currency',
    'align'     => 'right',
    'currency'  => 'order_currency_code',
    'fiter_index' => 'inovoicemain.subtotal_incl_tax'
));
$this->addColumn('subtotal', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('subtotal'),
    'index'     => 'subtotal',
    'type'      => 'currency',
    'align'     => 'right',
    'currency'  => 'order_currency_code',
    'fiter_index' => 'inovoicemain.subtotal'
));
```

Comment: Hey, I hope you will see this comment, but know, when I search billing with 'created at' array, I have an error : `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous` Any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

Please, look at the following article with extended information by this theme: http://www.widgetsandburritos.com/adding-fields-order-invoice-grid-magento/

But there described way for 1.4.1 where resource models logic was in Mysql4 models.

Also, look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684684/adding-to-grid-selection-for-grid-php-file